# Anyone know what "|B|" means?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a simple line of code, shown below, which is giving me a strange error.  I can't find any documentation on what that means.  Anyone know?

`h1 := input.time(timestamp('2023-03-13T20:10:00'))`

The error reads:

> Script could not be translated from: |B|h1 := input.time(timestamp('2023-03-13T20:10:00')

Any thoughts?

This innocuous code worked until recently. Maybe an invisible character?  I pasted the code into a text editor (notepad++) and copied, re-pasted into pinescript, and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your string for the timestamp is the problem.
Try :

```
h1 = input.time(timestamp("13 Mar 2023 20:10"), "Date")
```